# How to find every occurrence of pattern and match the whole line every time?

Tags: regex, kotlin

Today's regex problem is to get the provided pattern and every time it occurs, take the whole line. I've tried to make an approach:

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/Rfscug/1/)

I'm looking for any text in square brackets like: [foo], [bar] so pattern is `(\[([a-zA-Z]+?)\])`.

Now, to make it take the whole line I got this:

```regex
^.*(\[([a-zA-Z]+?)\]).*$
```

But that solution takes only the last occurrence of the pattern. Setting as non-greedy gives only the first occurrence.

In the provided link, the regex pattern should return 2 matches with the same whole line and pattern group found.

Does anyone have an idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: What programming language (or regex flavor) are you using?

Comment: Currently it's used for Kotlin.

Comment: It is not possible with regex. You could have done it had Kotlin regex had support for infinite width lookbehind patterns, then you could at least get three groups upon each match.

Comment: I could also split text with \n and iterate through all splits but I wonder if there's possibility to make that with only regex pattern.

Comment: @Andrew You could also just find the lines that contain at least one `[...]` (using `^.*\[[a-zA-Z]+\].*$`) and then iterate the matches to look for the sub-matches. This would be very easy in .NET because it supports repeating groups (AKA captures). Unfortunately, that's not supported by your regex engine.